# How to train OpenAi model to generate rules

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have a board game where all the players characteristics and rules are being randomised / generated. I’ve made a document to teach model - how game works, what characteristics it should generate and examples. How I can teach model with it? Tried GPT3-turbo but it has limit per conversation. Tried fine-tuned but I did not understand how to teach it.
Thank you in advance

Used fine-tuned model. Thought I can send the info to it, so it remembers and uses it, but it has only prompt -> completion

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I need algorithm solution, not code